# Unreal development kit export textures

Tags: graphics, export, textures, unreal-development-kit

I am not familiar wit UDK tool, bot I have complete source code (Binaries directory, Development directory, Engine directory and UDKGame directory) from one game and I want to export all textures from this project. How is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to export the textures from that game and use them for yourself? Most games' terms forbid this.

Comment: Yes. Source code is available only and can be reproduced.

Comment: I'm not talking about the source code license, but the license for assets. Allows that using the artworks/assets for other projects?

Comment: Yes, it is for educational purpouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UDKGame directory of the game should be a directory called Content. Copy all files in that directory to the directory of the same name of an installed version of UDK e.g. C:\UDK\UDK-2013-07\UDKGame\Content.

Start the UDK editor, the easiest way is to use the shortcut in the start menu called "UDK Editor". Open the Content Browser. If it is not already open, click on the black t symbol in the menu bar of the editor. The window of the content browser might be reduced to a little bar.

In the lower left of the Content Browser window, under "Packages", search for the name of the *.upk files you copied to the Content directory earlier. They are like zip files containing the textures among the assets of the game. But only the UDK Editor can view and interact with them.

When you are inspecting a upk/package look for icons with Texture2D written on them, these are textures. Right click on a Texture2d, choose "Export to File...".

If a package appears to be empty right click it and choose "fully load", the UDK Editor might not have it loaded yet.